# ACTION_QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, eclipse

Consider the following useless code in an Android activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String s1 = Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED;
    String s2 = Intent.ACTION_QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART;
}
```

Why does Eclipse raise an **ACTION_QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART cannot be resolved or is not a field** error? I mean, aren't both the two strings defined by the [Intent class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.2_r1/android/content/Intent.java?av=f)?

The application is using:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

but putting both to 17 doesn't change Eclipse behaviour.

Comment: Is it `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_RESTARTED`?

Comment: All I can find is that, ACTION_QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART is not given on the android documentation. Still it is the part of the Intent.java . ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED is a part of documentation ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED )

Comment: @Nizam No, it's ACTION_QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART, as it's written.

Comment: @AnhSirkDasarp So you're saying that Eclipse considers it not valid because it's not documented? But it is public on the class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hidden from the SDK because it is only meant to be used internally. That's why it says "Hide:" above it. The format of grepcode makes that hard to see.

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to ignore that error and compile anyway (for example when creating a class slightly different from one that comes with the sources which uses that final string)?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean in your example, but anything not exposed in the Android SDK is not meant to be used by third party developers, either because the APIs are likely to change (which would cause your app to break) or because the functionality is limited to system apps. This intent seems to only be received by system apps, since the docs say "Ask system services...". I assume system services means services obtained through Context.getSystemService.

Comment: Also, you are not building against that code when using the Android SDK, you are building against stubs generated from that code which only include non-hidden fields/methods/classes. That variable doesn't exist at all at compile time for your app.