# show dialog when clicking uninstall/disbale app from option menu launcher

Tags: android

I want to delete few folder which are created outside of application package. I want to delete those folders if I uninstall my app manually. please suggest any solution.

1. if I click uninstall/disable app from launchers option menu.
2. select my app.
3. it should delete those folders.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18816716/2431281