# how to know user remove/uninstall my Android app

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I want to know is there any method can detect my user uninstall/remove my Android app???
Although I have Google Analytic to know how many user uninstall my app.
But I want to know the exact data of how many user install my app.

If I know a method can run when user uninstall my app, then I will send message to my server
to let me know this user remove my app, also I can count how many people have uninstall/remove my app everyday.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: look into this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18816716/3326331)