# Android detect uninstall and open intent

Tags: java, android, ads

I found this service https://admin.appjolt.com/ but I don't know how it works. They are opening browser intent with their ad/cross promo when user decided to uninstall our application. Intent is opening when confirmation dialog shows.

Anybody knows the method? Receiver don't works, they are using some service and listening if some object exist or not. I don't know what they are listening actualy.

Answer (score 8):

This topic has already been discussed several times. You can find a detailed collections of partial solutions, examples and related limitations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18816716/2760919).

The short answer is that there's no **100% working** solutions without using root or acting as system app.

Answer (score 1):

Another option for detecting app uninstall is using native code - You need to monitor for Your directory using `inotify` framework in forked process. When it's deleted You run `am` command that starts `Intent`

PoC here: https://github.com/pelotasplus/ActionAfterUninstall/blob/master/app/src/main/jni/hello-jni.c

Comment: Note that this no longer works as of Android 5.0: https://github.com/pelotasplus/ActionAfterUninstall/issues/1

Answer (score 0):

I used this several times. Your app has to be installed as a Device administrator. Then you can be notified for different kind of events. Then you can easily create an Intent. I was personnaly sending a push notification.

Have a look at this : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Comment: Nope, this appjolt is not using device admin.

Comment: Well, there is another solution which is more battery consuming, but enables to know if other apps have been installed or uninstalled. Thanks to the package manager, you can get the a list of the packages (so apps) installed. So with a service, you can easily see if a package has been added or removed and trigger an event.

http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-installed-applications-with-name-package-name-version-and-icon

Comment: how? If app is coming to be uninstalled, package is reset.
I want to detect this uninstall intent in just moment before user clicks "ok" in uninstall dialog. It demands service but still I don't know how to capture this event ;)
I think this thread needs a bounty

Comment: With the package manager, you can get the list of all the packages installed. So basically, I think that you just have to store this list first and then compare the new list of installed package to the list saved. If you don't want your service to consume the whole battery, it won't be immediate but it will work.

Comment: You don't understand. After package deinstalation, I can't make any action from the same package because code is not exist any more! 
Application have to detect intent if user wants to uninstall it. How I can to compare list from service if system deleted service? :)

Comment: Yeah sorry, I'm really tired. I tought that there was an appjolt app monitoring the installed apps. I didn't realized that it was a sdk. Sorry :)