# How to check if user wants to uninstall my app?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast, uninstallation

I have been through with many Google solutions but not any solution is able to resolve my problem. What I am trying to do is firing a window for user to enter pin/password while he is trying to uninstall my application.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692571/how-it-works-warning-that-app-is-going-to-be-uninstalled) link, but I am facing 2 issues with this solution these are as follow:

1. I registered broadcast receiver in My Application, when I open "My Application" in settings, it does not seems working but working fine with other apps. My Code below:

   ```
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   /// fetching package names from extras
   String[] packageNames = intent.getStringArrayExtra("android.intent.extra.PACKAGES");

   if(packageNames!=null){
       for(String packageName: packageNames){
           if(packageName!=null && packageName.equals("com.android.systemapplication")){
               // User has selected our application under the Manage Apps settings
               // now initiating background thread to watch for activity
               new ListenActivities(context).start();
           }
         }
      }
   }
   ```
2. When I replaced package name with some different package name that settings screen can detect in broadcast receiver then in run(thread) it is not detecting uninstaller activity, Please see my ListenActivities as below:

   ```
   public void run(){

   Looper.prepare();

   while(!exit){

        // get the info from the currently running task
        List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(MAX_PRIORITY); 

        String activityName = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName();


        Log.d("topActivity", "CURRENT Activity ::"
                + activityName);
   // here "activityName" is "com.android.launcher" if I select 
   // package name it is "com.android.launcher2.launcher".

        if (activityName.equals("com.android.packageinstaller.UninstallerActivity")) {
           // User has clicked on the Uninstall button under the Manage Apps settings

            //do whatever pre-uninstallation task you want to perform here

            exit = true;
            Toast.makeText(context, "Done with preuninstallation tasks... Exiting Now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       } else if(activityName.equals("com.android.settings.ManageApplications")) {
           // back button was pressed and the user has been taken back to Manage Applications window
                     // we should close the activity monitoring now
           exit=true;
       }
   }
   Looper.loop();
   }
   ```

I saw many solutions but no success. if it is deprecated then please show some Android documentation because I can see antivirus can do same as what I am asking for. Code would be more helpful. ? Any help would be helpful.

Comment: I do not think this is ( and should ) be possible ( without root )

Comment: @ligi I can see few examples, can you give some google documentation or example to believe?

Comment: You mean you want to stop a user from uninstalling your app? I'd call that a virus.

Comment: It is not possible to detect in own app which itself is going to be uninstalled. that's a simple logic