# Android check own package uninstall

Tags: android, browser

I need to know when a user uninstall my application.

I did know that we can know other packages' uninstall, but we couldn't know ours.

But today I uninstalled UC Browser. And after uninstall I was redirected to a feedback Url of uc browser. How can it be ppossible, how can they know that I uninstalled and redirected me to a webage.

Comment: Due to a security flaw that I have been trying to get Google to fix. I have not tested recent versions of Android; hopefully it is now corrected on Android 5.x.

Comment: There's a lengthy discussion about such feature here ; http://stackoverflow.com/a/18816716/680519 . Seems to relate strongly on Android version you try such functionality on.