# How does Truecaller open webpage on uninstall?

Tags: android, android-intent

I installed TrueCaller today and after uninstall was complete, my chrome opened with a wufoo form to collect feedback. I did not know such a thing was possible! How can I do the same ?

Comment: I'm not sure if the method described [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692571/how-it-works-warning-that-app-is-going-to-be-uninstalled) still works, but you might have a look there.

Comment: May be this answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/18816716/5567009

Comment: Yes that seems to be right. I just installed truecaller and a few minutes after it was installed it tried to register a wufoo.com url with a shell call to system/bin/am (the android activity manager). Their method is an ELF binary: data/data/com.truecaller/monitor I blocked the attempt with XPrivacy.