# How to get notify before uninstalling app in android

Tags: android

I am working in app that needs to call an api, Webservice before uninstall app so please let me know if any solution to call before uninstall or any process that called before uninstall app.

Comment: This ain't possible, but there are some work arounds like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18816716/4782930)

Answer (score -1):

You could try adding a `BroadcastReceiver` listening for `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED` events.

Comment: Doesn't work: read [ACTION.PACKAGE.REMOVED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED). it says:  **The package that is being removed does not receive this Intent.**

Comment: My bad, I did not understand you wanted the uninstalled app to be notified. And I do not think this can be done...

Comment: No problem ;), your intentions were good. And u are right, this cannot be done, atleast... not without complex work arounds.

Comment: Hello guys, but i need solution with same app to getting notified before uninstall

Comment: @JamesGurera yeah we know, but you **can't** (yet?), [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692571/how-can-an-app-detect-that-its-going-to-be-uninstalled/18816716#18816716) is as close as you can get!

Answer (score -1):

You Register your BroadCastReceiver with this filter:

```
 <receiver android:name=".MyBroadCastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Doesn't work: read [ACTION.PACKAGE.REPLACED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED) it says: **A new version of an application package has been installed, replacing an existing version that was previously installed.** nothing about detecting uninstallation. This can be used for detecting updates.

Comment: This is what the [MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED) does! The OP want's to know how to catch his application being **uninstalled**. Not **replaced**.