# send the id to server with unique id if user installs

Tags: android, server, google-cloud-messaging

Please don't mark this as a duplicate,

I am trying to send the id to my online server. In that I have create a db and a table to store the id.

When user first installs the app, the id will send to the server. and it is working fine.

My question:
How to check whether the user (id) stored in table has installed my app or the app has been uninstalled from android device.

If user has uninstalled my app, then i want to remove the id from the table.

I am not using any username and password, to verify each user uniquely.

any kind of help is appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692571/how-can-an-app-detect-that-its-going-to-be-uninstalled

Comment: thanks dude, will check it

Answer (score 1):

U can store store imie number when user install the app and u can set one broadcastreveicer which will notify you when application will be uninstalled.

As per my knowledge this is the best solution among all.