# activity does not open on event detection

Tags: android

I am following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692571/how-can-an-app-detect-that-its-going-to-be-uninstalled/18816716#18816716) to implement app un-install detector. I am basically trying to open Main Activity when un-installation event is detected, but when I un-istall my app nothing happens (Main Activity does not open before un-install).

Please help, what is wrong with my code?

**MainAcivity:**

```
package com.example.appdeveloper.unistalltest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**Broadcast Receiver:**

```
package com.example.appdeveloper.unistalltest;


import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UninstallIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // fetching package names from extras
        String[] packageNames = intent.getStringArrayExtra("android.intent.extra.PACKAGES");

        if(packageNames!=null){
            for(String packageName: packageNames){
                if(packageName!=null && packageName.equals("com.example.appdeveloper.unistalltest")){
                    // User has selected our application under the Manage Apps settings
                    // now initiating background thread to watch for activity
                    new ListenActivities(context).start();
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "No package found in Broadcast Receiver", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

**ListenActivities.java:**

```
package com.example.appdeveloper.unistalltest;

import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.List;


public class ListenActivities extends Thread {

    boolean exit = false;
    ActivityManager am = null;
    Context context = null;

    public ListenActivities(Context con){
        context = con;
        am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    }

    public void run(){

        Looper.prepare();

        while(!exit){

            // get the info from the currently running task
            List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(MAX_PRIORITY);

            String activityName = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName();

            Log.d("topActivity", "CURRENT Activity ::"
                    + activityName);

            if (activityName.equals("com.android.packageinstaller.UninstallerActivity")) {
                // User has clicked on the Uninstall button under the Manage Apps settings

                //do whatever pre-uninstallation task you want to perform here
                // show dialogue or start another activity or database operations etc..etc..

                context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));

                exit = true;
                Toast.makeText(context, "Done with preuninstallation tasks... Exiting Now", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if(activityName.equals("com.android.settings.ManageApplications")) {
                // back button was pressed and the user has been taken back to Manage Applications window
                // we should close the activity monitoring now
                exit=true;
            }
        }
        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.appdeveloper.unistalltest">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".UninstallIntentReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="0">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART" />
                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: First, `QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART` is not part of the Android SDK. Second, `QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART` will never be sent to your own app, at least on Android 4.0+. Third, `getRunningTasks()` will not do what you want on Android 5.0+ for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: @CommonsWare then what should I do to detect when my app is being un-installed? my android version is kitkat

Comment: "then what should I do to detect when my app is being un-installed?" -- hopefully that is no longer possible. To the extent that it is, it represents a security flaw in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Your app can't know when the user uninstall it since Android 4.0+. I had a similar problem, but didn't found a way to do it. The only things I found today (i already gave up with my app, but maybe it can help you) is this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html
I'm not sure this will help you, but it is the only thing i found.