# Is it possible to attach a custom parameter on an automatically collected event on firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, uninstallation, firebase-analytics

There is an automatically collected event called `app_remove` in firebase analytics and I'm wondering if I can attach a custom parameter to that.

What I want to do is to track users who uninstalled my app. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692571/how-can-an-app-detect-that-its-going-to-be-uninstalled) of course but it won't work on Lollipop version and above.

So I'm wondering if something like this will work:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("user_email", email);
// attach bundle to app_remove event
```

or perhaps I can set the `userId`:

```
firebaseAnalytics.setUserId(email);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, you can't change the way that automatically collected events are reported.  You can only set attributes on events that you create and report in your code.