# how can i delete a folder on app deletion which was made by app outside the appfolder

Tags: android

I made an application from which I make a folder and save some files in it.

What I want is, when I delete the application the folder that I make outside from application should be deleted.

Comment: If you want your directory to be deleted on app uninstall then you should create it inside your cache directory. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir()

Answer (score 0):

Add your manifest following permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Then java code

```
File dir = getActivity().getFilesDir();
if (dir.isDirectory()) 
{
String[] subDir = dir.list();
for (int i = 0; i < subDir.length;i++)
{
   new File(dir, subDir[i]).delete();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18816716/997478) link to listen to when your application is being uninstalled, and in the callback, delete the folder using @sasikumar's code below. Hope this helps.