# Uninstall other package when uninstall my app

Tags: java, android

I have an app for downloading and installing themes. Can I somehow uninstall the earlier installed themes (installed with my app) if the user uninstalls my app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692571/how-can-an-app-detect-that-its-going-to-be-uninstalled

Comment: you basically can't uninstall other apps from within your app.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but there is no support for this kind of app-level dependency mechanism in Android.