# How to save Shared preferences data after android application is uninstalled

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, uninstallation

Recently I am saving data in shared preferences when user is login. 
Now if application is uninstalled then data of shared preferences saved. when user reinstall application get that data again don't want to login again:

```
android:allowBackup="true"
android:fullBackupOnly="true"
```

Shared preference code

```
public class SharedPrefManager {
//the constants
private static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "simplifiedcodingsharedpref";
private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "keyusername";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "keyemail";
private static final String KEY_api_token = "api_token";
private static final String KEY_role = "role";
private static final String KEY_ID = "keyid";

private static SharedPrefManager mInstance;
private static Context mCtx;

private SharedPrefManager(Context context) {
    mCtx = context;
}

public static synchronized SharedPrefManager getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new SharedPrefManager(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

//method to let the user login
//this method will store the user data in shared preferences
public void userLogin(User user) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(KEY_ID, user.getId());
    editor.putString(KEY_USERNAME, user.getUsername());
    editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, user.getEmail());
    editor.putString(KEY_api_token, user.getapi_token());
    editor.putString(KEY_role, user.getrole());
    editor.apply();
}

//this method will checker whether user is already logged in or not
public boolean isLoggedIn() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USERNAME, null) != null;
}

//this method will give the logged in user
public User getUser() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return new User(
            sharedPreferences.getInt(KEY_ID, -1),
            sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USERNAME, null),
            sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null),
            sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_api_token, null),
            sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_role, null)
    );
}
}
```

Comment: `android:allowBackup="false"`

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18816716/6727154

Comment: How is it supposed to work? You're only storing some values locally without any logic to manage users, verify if a user exists, creating new users and so on. As a side note, you're storing Context on a static field which creates memory leaks.

Comment: ^ it *can* create a memory leak. If this class is initialized with the application context, it's not a problem

Comment: As mentioned, set allowBackup to `false` in the manifest