# detect user when uninstall app in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, uninstallation

I want in flutter app, when user uninstall app, detect user and send message for her/his.
I use firebase and have private server and database(I don't have database in firebase).
how can do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18816716/11789675

Comment: check here, you can get idea

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to do this on the client.  When the app is uninstalled, no notification is given to it.  You could do it in the backend by using a keep-alive  (have the client send a message one a day to the server.  If you don't get a message within about 30 hours, its almost certainly been uninstalled (or the user has his phone off)).  But there's no way to do it client side.