# how is user data removed from the cloud if their user has uninstalled the app from their phone?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, cloud

Let's say I am using a notes app and the notes are saved on some cloud platform by the app. Let's say, I uninstall the app from my phone, how does the data from the cloud platform get removed? I am sure there is no way to know or find out that some user uninstalled the app

I haven't tried anything

Comment: You don't know if the user uninstalled the app.  Aside from the costs of storing that data you probably don't need to worry about it. You could track when a user last used the app and delete their data after some time if they don't use the app, but you have to find an appropriate time period that isn't too short or too long.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use `Receiver` to detect the uninstallation.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692571/how-can-an-app-detect-that-its-going-to-be-uninstalled).

The answer describes some limitations.

I don't know why you want to delete the cloud data when you uninstall the app. Then, why don't you keep the data in the local storage? The behaviour you want is just like that.

Comment: My question is more generic like how do companies deal with this situation. Like if a user deletes the app and the data was kept in the cloud, that means the company is responsible to remove the data from the cloud right? So, how do they deal with that

Comment: @pandyama Not always, I think it's XYproblem. Why do you exactly want to delete the data stored in the cloud? Normally, companies don't delete the data until they request, for example, deleting the account. There are a lot of reasons of using cloud server. One reason is to keep data even after uninstalling the app and when the user come back, the data are used again.

Comment: let me extend my question... from compliance stand point, if a user uninstalls an app, aren't the companies responsible to remove the data? Also, I am talking about an app where there is no user profile, like a simple notes app

Comment: @pandyama Well, I guess it depends on the country where you live in. For the note apps, as I said, you don't really need to store the data in the cloud. What's the point of saving data in the cloud server it will be removed after unstalling the app. There are many simple note apps, but you mean the apps that you don't need to sign in, right? Then, what's the point of using the server and waste resorce and money for the maintenance?

Comment: And there are law. So, you can check them. Normally, the apps that has signing, the user data will be removed after they remove their data or after certain year like a year or two years if he doesn't use the service anymore. This question is not about programming though.

Comment: You need to have an unregister or delete account option in your app that will remove the user account and any associated data. BTW, what if the user installed the app on multiple device and remove it only from one ?